# Angular JS ng-options default selection by object ID

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

Say i have these options from the database

```
$scope.options = [
 { id: 192, value: 'Bank 1'},
 { id: 168, value: 'Bank 2'},
 { id: 0,   value: 'Bank 3'},
];
```

and that this code works for setting default values by selecting the array position

```
<select ng-init="data.bankoptions=options[0]" ng-model="data.bankoptions" ng-options="bank.label for bank in options track by bank.id">
```

> and will display Bank 1 as default

How do i make it to set the default selection according to the object id? by selecting 192, 168 or 0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = {
   availableoptions: [],
   selectedoption: {}
};
```

Add data to options

> data.availableoptions.push({id: 192, label: 'Bank1'});

Set default selection

> data.selectedoption = { id: 192}

Get default selection

> $scope.default = data.selectedoption;

the select tag

```
<select ng-model="default" ng-options="bank.label for bank in data.availableoptions track by bank.id">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`select` **`as`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-) expression

```
ng-options="bank.id as bank.label for bank in options"
```